# Telling the content of an iFrame the orientation

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, orientation

I currently have a web site with an iFrame that is designed for a tablet device (eg iPad).
I am able to detect orientation in the parent to change the width and height of the iFrame itself, but I can't seem to get the iFrame page to detect the orientation of the device upon change.

I know if I load the actual page from the iFrame itself in Safari Mobile without being in an iFrame, it detects changes and rotates according to the orientation at that time.
If I load the page in landscape when its in the iFrame, it load the content in landscape, and visa-versa with being in portrait.
It seems that it doesn't want to constantly detect orientation after it has loaded itself when in an iFrame, only upon initial load.

Is there a way to tell the iFrame that the orientation has changed in some way? I have used this code, but without success:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(){
                var iframe = document.getElementById("youriframe").contentWindow;
                iframe.postMessage({
                    orientation: window.orientation
                }, 'http://the.domain.of.the.iframe.com');
}, false)
```

What makes it harder is that I can't edit the content of the iFrame as it isn't mine! The code below is what you're meant to inject into it!

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
            var newOrientationValue = e.data.orientation;
            alert(newOrientationValue); // <--- DO your own logic HERE
}, false)
```

Please help, I'be been racking my brain over this for days!
Hope that all makes sense.

Comment: I just implemented the plugin 'Child Browser' for PhoneGap and simply change the odd thing or too and now if I trigger the frame to open in 'Child Browser', it will orientate accordingly ^.^